# IQueryable Include not giving correct results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable

I have a generic repository implementation that creates an IQueryable as follows:

```
    internal IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
                                Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
                                List<Expression<Func<T, object>>> includeProperties = null,
                                int? page = null,
                                int? pageSize = null)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = m_dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
            query = query.Where(filter);

        if (orderBy != null)
            query = orderBy(query);

        if (page != null && pageSize != null)
            query = query.Skip((page.Value - 1) * pageSize.Value)
                         .Take(pageSize.Value);

        if (includeProperties != null)
            includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));

        return query.ToList();
   }
```

The problem that I'm having is that the Expression I pass to the include does not get included in the output of the query. The SQL that is generated does not include the JOIN.

I have no other parameters on the query. Filter, orderBy, page and pageSize are all null. The List of includes contains a single Expression and the member referred to by the Expression is declared as

```
   public virtual MyType m_Member { get; set; }
```

within the POCO class for the Repository objects.

I've read that IQueryable drops the Include on a Select or Projection but I'm not doing either here I believe. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign the result of the aggregation to `query`, I think:

```
query = includeProperties.Aggregate(query, ...);
```